# "The query argument is unknown error" for query types generated by graphql-codegen

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-client, graphql-codegen

I'm using Pothos to build a graphql schema and graphql-codegen to generate types based on this schema. The server runs via graphql-yoga and nextjs and the actual query works fine when run via the graphiql interface. I've been trying to set this up so my gql schema is typed properly with apollo client based on [this article](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/static-typing/).

Snipped of the schema builder:

```
builder.queryType({
  fields: t => ({
    greetings: t.string({
      resolve: (root, args, context) => `Welcome ${context.session?.user?.nickname}`
    })
  })
})
```

graphql-codegen generates the following type in the written `.ts` file so I know it's seeing the right schema.

```
export type Query = {
  __typename?: 'Query';
  greetings: Scalars['String'];
}
```

However, when I import the gql file per the codegen docs, it returns `unknown` and VSCode's hover window says "The query argument is unknown! Please regenerate the types." I've tried regenerating and rebooting VSCode and nothing changes.

```
import { gql } from '@/gql/gql'

const query = gql('query { greetings }')
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, as others mentioned, it was a problem with `documents` path in `codegen.ts`. I had my queries in `.ts` files, so I had to change my `documents` glob pattern to

```
documents: ["src/**/*.ts?(x)"],
```

And it's better to remove `ignoreNoDocuments: true` as it can mislead you.

Answer (score 3):

The issue for me was also where I specifying for codegen to look for my documents. The apollo documentation has you use

```
ignoreNoDocuments: true
```

in the codegen config which allows codegen to not-exit if it finds no documents. If you remove that config and run codegen you'll see
`Unable to find any GraphQL type definitions for the following pointers: - src/**/*.tsx`

I couldn't figure out how to get codegen to find the queries I defined at the top of my component `.tsx` files but was able to get it to work by defining them in `.graphql` files and then pointing codegen to that directory using

```
documents: ["./graphql/**/*.graphql"],
```

This article has an explanation for how to do this -> https://novu.co/blog/making-graphql-codegen-work-for-you-graphql-integration-with-react-and-typescript/

Answer (score 1):

What solved it for me was the documents setting in codegen.ts. I'm in a nextjs app with code in the pages folder but the example codegen.ts used src. After updating

```
  documents: ["src/**/*.tsx"],
```

to

```
  documents: ["pages/**/*.tsx"],
```

and regenerating I stopped getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers stated, this is definitely an issue with the supplied document paths. I want to share a misunderstanding I had about which documents to supply

I was supplying:
`documents: ["path/to/my/schema/and/resolver/definitions.ts"]`

What codegen actually needs is:
`documents: ["path/to/files/acting/as/clients.ts"]`

In other words, the file you supply should be the one that has this query:

```
'query { hello }'
```

**NOT** the one that has the query definition:

```
type Query {
  hello: String!
}
```